# Appdomain.Load(AssemblyName) raises file not found exception

Tags: c#, sandbox, appdomain

This snippet works fine:

```c#
System.Security.PermissionSet PS = new System.Security.PermissionSet(PermissionState.None);
PS.AddPermission(new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.AllAccess, Path));
PS.AddPermission(new SecurityPermission(SecurityPermissionFlag.Execution));
AppDomainSetup ADS = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation;
AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Pluging", null, ADS, PS, null);
Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFile(DLLPath); 
domain.Load(asm.FullName);
```

Creating a new AppDomainSetup fails:

```c#
System.Security.PermissionSet PS = new System.Security.PermissionSet(PermissionState.None);
PS.AddPermission(new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.AllAccess, Path));
PS.AddPermission(new SecurityPermission(SecurityPermissionFlag.Execution));
AppDomainSetup ADS = new AppDomainSetup();
ADS.ApplicationBase= Path;
AppDomain domain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Pluging", null, ADS, PS, null);
Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFile(DLLPath); 
domain.Load(asm.FullName);
```

The whole thing is running inside an asp.net project developed in VS2012.

this is the exception I receive:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'MacroBase, Version=1.0.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system 
cannot find the file specified.
```

could you please help?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I used to rename dlls before storing them. I still don't know the work around but I changed my algorithm so that I can store and recall dll with the same name as it was originally compiled. Problem solved.

What was the effect of changing AppDomainSetup? In first alternative, asp.net was finding a copy of that renamed dll (with original name) in bin directory of asp.net project.